# Передача параметра в шаблон Django. Отображение картинки в браузере

Tags: python, django

```
код во views.py

def getFrame(request):
    data = request.GET
    name_video = data.get('video')
    name_picture = frame_one('videos/' + name_video)

    return render(request, 'opencv/GetFrame.html', {'name':name_picture})
```

В результате работы метода

```
frame_one
```

в папке

```
static/img
```

создается картинка,которую я хочу вывести в браузере. name_picture - имя этой картинки + расширение, например 1.jpg

Далее код шаблона

```
<svg width="1280" height="720" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left:60px">
     <image class='frame' xlink:href='{% static "img/{{name}}" %}'></image>
</svg>
```

В результате,при обращении по url, обработчик которого написан выше получаю ошибку

```
 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/img/%7B%7B%20name%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Но если в этой строчке написать так

```
<image class='frame' xlink:href='{% static "img/1.jpg" %}'></image>
```

То получим как и хотели картинку
То есть получить через {{ name }} параметр и записать его в свойство xlink:href не получается. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: а если так? `<image class='frame' xlink:href='{% static "img/" %}{{name}}'>`

Comment: В каталоге static должны храниться только статические данные проекта (стили, скрипты и т.п.), которые сами по себе никогда не меняются. Для меняющихся данных следует использовать каталог media.

Comment: Работает,спасибо. В документации описано,не нашел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<image class='frame' xlink:href='{% static "img/" %}{{name}}'>
```

Но как вам уже сказали, *в каталоге static должны храниться только статические данные проекта (стили, скрипты и т.п.), которые сами по себе никогда не меняются. Для меняющихся данных следует использовать каталог media*.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Строго говоря, в общем случае такое конструирование ссылок может не сработать, потому что Storage имеют право видоизменять ссылки на своё усмотрение. На счастье автора, стандартные FileSystemStorage и StaticFilesStorage ссылки не видоизменяют, поэтому повезло что работает